# Unable to extract a data from Table using inner join on same table

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

Trying to extract the data from table called `TB_Emloyee`. There are 4 columns in table with `C_ID, Name, Department, Count`.

My table has following data

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e74be

I would like to have following output.

```
C_ID   NAme    Department  Count    
200    Max     IH          2    
100    David   PR          1    
101    Lex     PR          1    
102    Alex    IT          2    
103    Slava   IH          1    
104    Tunja   PR          2
```

Until now I have tried the following, but I am not able to get the whole data.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e74be/2/0

I am not an expert with inner query so help me with situation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a self join to pick highest count row

```
select a.*
from Tb_Employee a
left join Tb_Employee b
        on a.c_ID = b.c_ID
        and a.Name = b.Name
        and a.department = b.department
        and a.Count < b.Count
where b.c_ID is null
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e74be/10)

Comment: @M Khalid junaid , what happen if i have more than 12 Column than for each colum i have to wirte a.'ColunName' = b.'ColumnName' or is there any other way. your solution is working as of now. check this link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56fe88/1

Comment: @user1521171 i join part you have to include only those columns which are repeated, if all columns have repeated values but with different count values then yes these should be present in on clause

Comment: @M Khalid junaid It seems like that your solution is working on the sample database but it is not working on my current database. I have add my orginal database on this link. where LFD_Nr and Historie is two primary key. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2940e/2

Comment: @user1521171 can you tell me what is your grouping criteria if its only `LFD_NR` then remove `and a.Datum= b.Datum` like http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2940e/3

Answer (score 0):

Just add `Name` and `department` fields like this:

```
SELECT
    C_ID, Name, department,
    max(Count) AS max_count
FROM
  Tb_Employee
GROUP BY
  C_ID, Name, department;
```

Provided that `Name` and `department` have the same values for the same `C_ID`.

If you are designing the database schema, you should [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) the tables better.

Answer (score 0):

Though I agree with @Kriz Poon in that you should normalize your tables. TO get the output you want there is no need to `GROUP` more columns. Just change the columns you actually want to select.

```
SELECT
    `c_ID`, `Name`, `department`, max(`Count`) AS `Count`
FROM
    Tb_Employee
GROUP BY
    C_ID
;
```

Comment: this qery seems working but I have mess up my database I forget to add one more column check this below link and for this type of schema the query is not working. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56fe88/1

Comment: your solution is also working but somehow its not working in Access.

Comment: @user1521171 Hmm that's weird, Sadly I don't have acces to Acces and thus unable to test this. What is the error you're getting?